# Converting DOM elements to an image: words converted to dashes (jQuery, HTML5, SVG)

Tags: jquery, image, html, canvas, svg

I have a question regarding the process of converting HTML to an image.

I have been using code similar to the code snippet found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas).

Everything seems to be working fine, except the image I get has turned **some** of the words into dashes. So, something that might say "submit" on the page will now say "-" in the image. Similarly, something that might say "Have a Suggestion?" on the page will now say "---" in the image. Otherwise, all of the proportions, formatting, and colors are correct. I am only having a problem with some of the text. I am not having problems with text inside textarea tags.

```
function createImage() {

    var canvas = $('<canvas/>');
    var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
    var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='1000' height='1000'>" +
                 "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
                   "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>" +
                     $("body").html() +
                   "</div>" +
                 "</foreignObject>" +
               "</svg>";
    var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
    var img = new Image();
    var svg = new Blob([data], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
    img.src = url;
    return img;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly in the rendered graphic, the text label is too small to accommodate the word. This probably depends on how the canvas interprets scaling and font sizes? It's just a guess though.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the font size from percentage to pixel. It was font-size: 100%; I had to set it to font-size: 34px.